# Difference between table fillfactor and index fillfactor

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, one can set fillfactor for an index as well as a table. What is the difference? How to decide values for either. What are the usecases?

I am trying to cluster a spatial relation on a spatial index. It has a couple of million records. The records are updated all the time though very few new ones are created daily.

The use case is spatial range queries.
What will be a good value for the table fillfactor and / or the index fillfactor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [CREATE TABLE manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html) (emphasis added):

> The fillfactor for **a table** is a percentage between 10 and 100. 100 (complete packing) is the default. When a smaller fillfactor is specified, INSERT operations pack table pages only to the indicated percentage; the remaining space on each page is reserved for updating rows on that page. This gives UPDATE a chance to place the updated copy of a row on the same page as the original, which is more efficient than placing it on a different page. **For a table whose entries are never updated, complete packing is the best choice, but in heavily updated tables smaller fillfactors are appropriate.**

From the [CREATE INDEX manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createindex.html) (emphasis added):

> The fillfactor for an **index** is a percentage that determines how full
>   the index method will try to pack index pages. For B-trees, leaf pages
>   are filled to this percentage during initial index build, and also
>   when extending the index at the right (largest key values). If pages
>   subsequently become completely full, they will be split, leading to
>   gradual degradation in the index's efficiency. **B-trees use a default
>   fillfactor of 90, but any value from 10 to 100 can be selected. If the
>   table is static then fillfactor 100 is best to minimize the index's
>   physical size, but for heavily updated tables a smaller fillfactor is
>   better to minimize the need for page splits. The other index methods
>   use fillfactor in different but roughly analogous ways; the default
>   fillfactor varies between methods.**

Comment: It's customary to mention the source of a quote. Even if it's easy to figure out.

Comment: yeah, sure ) forget sometimes...

Comment: Sorry to nag some more. Please link to the current version of the manual (unless you need to address a particular one). I edited. [More about that here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual).

Comment: The links are backwards.

Comment: Re: "If the table is static then fillfactor 100 is best to minimize the index's physical size, but for heavily updated tables a smaller fillfactor is better to minimize the need for page splits." Trying to understand context of "heavily updated tables" - does that mean table with row values that are heavily updated, or perhaps could that also include tables with rows that are frequently inserted and/or deleted? I wanted to know if my table, with few changes to row values but extensive inserts and deletes, might benefit from lower fillfactor on it's principal (key) index.

Comment: @Reinsbrain I think updates and deletes are operational pretty similar under mvcc, so I think they would benefit (updates could be placed on disk beside the previous version). I'm not sure about inserts; I believe postgres basically appends inserted rows but it's probably more complicated than that